# How to pass argument from one function to another in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass argument from one function to another so i can pass params to backend when user execute `deleteProcess` i have modal window open there i have `yesCallback` that means if user click on yes then only delete.

So `deleteProcess` has params how can i pass to `deleteInventory` so i can send it to backend using `prcDeleteFactory.deletePrcInventory(inventory,processId);`.

ctrl.js

```
 function deleteInventory(inventory, processId) {
      console.log("facotry executed");
      $scope.confirmationWin.close();
      prcDeleteFactory.deletePrcInventory(inventory, processId);
  }
  $scope.deleteProcess = function(inventory) {
      var inventory = inventory;
      var processId = $stateParams.processId;
      $scope.confirmationWin.open().center();
      $scope.messageText = $scope.processDTO.deleteMessageToDisplay;
      $scope.yesCallback = deleteInventory(invenotry, processId);
  }
```

Comment: You spelled it `invenotry` instead of `inventory` in the call to `deleteInventory()`.

Comment: Thanks i did notice that resolve the problem.